# Como remover encapsulamento xml em json retornado por WebService

Tags: c#, web-service, webforms

Criei o seguinte método:

```cs
[WebService(Namespace = "http://myDomain.com.br/PublicacaoService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class PublicacaoService : CustomWebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("UserAuthentication")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
    public string ObterDiretorios()
    {
        CheckHeader();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            title = "Raíz",
            key = "raiz",
            folder = true
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Mas na hora que faço um teste pelo browser ele me retorna o seguinte:

```xml
<string xmlns="http://myDomain.com.br/PublicacaoService">
    {"title":"Raíz","key":"raiz","folder":true}
</string>
```

Bom, esse modelo é para exemplo.
Estou montando uma árvore de diretórios com o ***fancytree*** e estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#directoryTree").fancytree({
            source: {
                url: "/Services/PublicacaoService.asmx/ObterDiretorios"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Mas quando testo, a árvore não é criada.
E quando tento pegar o resultado ***json*** apenas e jogar diretamente no ***fancytree***, funciona:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#directoryTree").fancytree({
            source: [
                {"title":"Raíz","key":"raiz","folder":true}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

O que me faz pensar que o encapsulamento do ***json*** feito com ***xml*** não está sendo reconhecido pelo ***fancytree***.

**Logo, como faço para remover esse encapsulamento com *xml* e deixar apenas o valor *json* como retorno?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escreva o retorno em `Context.Response`, não como retorno direto da função:

```
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("UserAuthentication")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
public void ObterDiretorios()
{
    CheckHeader();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string strJSON = serializer.Serialize(new
    {
        title = "Raíz",
        key = "raiz",
        folder = true
    });

    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Context.Response.Flush();
    Context.Response.Write(strJSON);
}
```